# Why is this sequence of images correct?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, sequence

There are currently 33 questions on Mensa's "[Online IQ Test](https://www.mensa.lu/en/mensa/online-iq-test.html)" which I took for fun. I correctly answered 32 questions and understand why they are correct, but there is one remaining question (to which I only know the answer to because answers are hardcoded in the page's JS) whose answer I do not understand.

Can someone explain to me why the following is correct (question 11)?

> [image: Answer D in question 11 is correct, but why?]

I'm not saying it shouldn't be correct - just that I don't understand why. I don't follow the progression at all.

Comment: With most 'IQ tests', it's more a matter of 'the person who invented the puzzle thought of this one particular undefined sequence, with a weird rule which is just as weird as any of the rules that could generate the other answers'.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. I just felt it was strange that I was able to figure out all of the other "weird rules" except this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if we consider every image has a center. the first image has 2 lines, second image has 3 lines which is (2+1) and the third has 5 (3+2). so the final image can have 8 lines(5+3).

Comment: Maybe mention what that sequence is famously called?

Comment: Thanks! What I think threw me off was getting stuck on thinking the first image had just one line.

Comment: @APrough if you're referring to the Fibonacci sequence, there's not enough data to know that this is one. 2, 3, 5, 8 are certainly part of a Fibonacci sequence which starts at one, but it could also be part of the following sequence: 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 17, etc (which I think is more likely)

Comment: I thought it was 1 line, 3 lines, 5 lines, and I answered C which was 7 lines (and also incorrect).

Comment: @Timothy, if the first image is 1 line then why isn't the third 3 lines (or 2 and a half)?

Comment: @Octopus, because the first image isn't one line. I'm not claiming it is. I was just explaining where my mental block was. I was incorrect, but I didn't understand why I was incorrect. Now that it's been pointed out to me it seems obvious, but I needed help getting there.